# Using Nested Loops in Searching Two Vectors and Looking at Their Attributes

Tags: c++, vector

How do you use a nested loop to find every object in a vector and test one of its attributes to another variable, and if it matches put that into a function?

(doing this with two vectors at once)

To clarify

Let's say there was a player class and an enemy class both with an `id` integer:

```
class player{
public:
int id;
};

class enemy{
public:
int id;
};
```

And then there would be a vector holding objects of those classes:

```
vector<player> allPlayers;
vector<enemy> allEnemies;

player playerTest1;
playerTest1.id = 1;

allPlayers.push_back(playerTest1);

player playerTest2;
playerTest1.id = 2;

allPlayers.push_back(playerTest2);

enemy enemyTest1;
enemyTest1.id = 1;

allEnemies.push_back(enemyTest1);

enemy enemyTest2;
enemyTest2.id = 2;

allEnemies.push_back(enemyTest2);

enemy enemyTest3;
enemyTest3.id = 3;

allEnemies.push_back(enemyTest3);
```

Then there would be a function that would output the objects id's:

```
int outputIds(player &player, enemy &enemy) {
cout << player.id << endl;
cout << enemy.id << endl; 
}
```

After that a prompt would ask for player id and enemy id:

```
int uid1;
int uid2;

cout << "\nEnter your Id (1-2): ";
cin >> uid1;
cout << "\nEnter your Enemies Id (1-3): ";
cin >> uid2;
//how do I use the function above based on what the user inputted using nested looping through a vector?
```

What I can't figure out is how to use nested looping to use the `uid` the user enters to find an object's id and then put that into the `outputIds` function

Comment: I see absolutely no reason to nest the loops. Have one loop that finds a player, and another that finds an enemy. When you have that working, consider using [maps](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/Map.html) instead of vectors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here I wrote a simple solution for what you're trying to achieve.

```
vector<player>::iterator player_iter = allPlayers.begin();                    
vector<enemy>::iterator enemy_iter;
bool found = false;

// try to find player
while (player_iter != allPlayers.end() && !found) {
    if (player_iter->id == uid1)
        found = true;
    else 
        player_iter++;
}

// when player has been found, try to find enemy
if (found) {
    found = false;
    enemy_iter = allEnemies.begin();

    while (enemy_iter != allEnemies.end() && !found) {
        if (enemy_iter->id == uid2)
            found = true;
        else 
            enemy_iter++;
}

// if both have been found call function outputIds
if (found)
    outputIds(*player_iter, *enemy_iter);
```

Answer (score 0):

With `std::find_if` in `<algorithm>`:

```
std::vector<player> allPlayers = {1, 2};
std::vector<enemy> allEnemies = {1, 2, 3};

int uid1;
int uid2;

std::cout << "\nEnter your Id (1-2): ";
std::cin >> uid1;
std::cout << "\nEnter your Enemies Id (1-3): ";
std::cin >> uid2;

auto playerIt = std::find_if(allPlayers.begin(), allPlayers.end(),
                             [=](const player& p) { return p.id = uid1; });
auto enemyIt = std::find_if(allEnemies.begin(), allEnemies.end(),
                            [=](const enemy& e) { return e.id = uid2; });

if (playerIt != allPlayers.end() && enemyIt  != allEnemies.end()) {
    outputIds(*playerIt, *enemyIt);
}
```